# Python remove duplicates from lists and sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, count

I want to remove duplicates from my output so it looks like this:

```
 Boston Americans 1
 New York Giants 5
 Chicago White Sox 3
 Chicago Cubs 2
 Pittsburgh Pirates 5
```

And i would like to sort my items alphabetically and print them.
And in different part of program print items by numbers of wins.

Output I get: Not showing every part of my list, but item counts are correct

```
['Boston Americans', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Pittsburgh Pirates']

Boston Americans 1
New York Giants 5
Chicago White Sox 3
Chicago Cubs 2
Chicago Cubs 2
Pittsburgh Pirates 5
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
winners=[]
with open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.strip()
        winners.append(a)
print(winners)

for n in winners:
    if n in winners:
        print(n, winners.count(n))

name=input("Enter some team name: ")
print("They won world cup:",  winners.count(name))

main()
```

Comment: "sort my items alphabetical and by numbers of wins": which one should take precedence? The alphabetical sorting I think (from your example)?

Comment: I mean, i want to print them both.

Comment: `for n in winners: if n in winners:`: that if clause will always be True, of course.

Comment: That's not what you're saying: you're saying you want to *sort* them alphabetically *and* by numbers of wins.

Answer (score 2):

this give you a list of sorted unique values:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    values = sorted(set([strip(l[:-1]) for l in f.readlines()]))

print "\n".join(values)
```

produce

```
Boston Americans 1
Chicago Cubs 2
Chicago White Sox 3
New York Giants 5
Pittsburgh Pirates 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a `collections.Counter` (from the standard library) , that's what it's made for:

```
import collections

l = ['Boston Americans', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Pittsburgh Pirates']
c = collections.Counter(l)
for name, score in c.most_common():
    print name,  score

# or use c.get(name) to get to a team's score directly
```

In your case you don't even need the intermediary list (as suggested by Marcin below):

```
with open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt", "r") as f:
    c = collections.Counter(winner.strip() for winner in f)
# Do the for name, score... thing above
```

(Consider using `reversed(c.most_common())` to get the items in ascending order)

Comment: What about adding the scores together from the text file?

Comment: @Marcin I was working from the list shown a little bit above, but you're right: I suppose using `collections.Counter(winner.strip() for winner in f)` would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to the main function. Its not the most beautiful code, but than I did not want totally change your function. For better solutions look at Counter or defaultdict like in the other answer.

```
def main():
    winners=[]
    with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            # split the line and separate team name from the score
            split_line=line.strip().split()
            winners.append((" ".join(split_line[0:-1]), int(split_line[-1])))
    print(winners)

    # use a dict to sum up the scores
    out_dict = {};

    for team_name, score in winners:
        if team_name not in out_dict:
            out_dict[team_name] = int(score)
        else:
            out_dict[team_name] += int(score)

    # sort the out_dict using both team name and the score, and print the result
    for k,v in sorted(out_dict.items(), key = lambda kv: (kv[0],kv[1])):
        print(k,v)
```

The result is:

```
('Boston Americans', 1)
('Chicago Cubs', 6)
('Chicago White Sox', 3)
('New York Giants', 8)
('Pittsburgh Pirates', 7)
```

The test input file:

```
Boston Americans 1
New York Giants 5
Chicago White Sox 3
Chicago Cubs 2
New York Giants 3
Chicago Cubs 2
Pittsburgh Pirates 5
Chicago Cubs 2
Pittsburgh Pirates 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary will reduce the code further to:

```
def main():
    winners={}
    with open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.strip()
        winners[a] = winners.setdefault(a, 0) + 1
    for winner in winners.keys().sort():
        print winner, winners[winner]
```

If sorting through the item count is required, go with a [Named Tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) rather than the dictionary. Advantage will be that you can sort in both the ways using the sorted method for values.